# how to resize string [ group of numbers and char]?

Tags: c, data-structures, encryption

Good Afternoon all,
I am working over rsa encryption and decryption, for more security i am also using padding in cipher text, for different input (amit) , i am getting different length output like-

```
plain text- amit     
cipher text-10001123A234A987A765A
```

My problem is- For big plain text ,my algo generate large size cipher text, and i thought,
 it is wastage of resources  to keep long string in database ,
Is there any way with the help of that i can compact cipher and convert real cipher when i will require?

Comment: is there any way, any algo which i can apply for sizing of cipher text , but for decryption i required the same cipher so we can easy get real cipher.

Comment: You want a magical, reversible crypto function that shrinks your data down to smaller than it was before, then automagically regains that lost information on decryption? So do I! If you find one, please let me know, and we'll share the £trillions fifty-fifty. Cheers.

Comment: Man, I'm keeping all my books in my bookshelf and I do want to keep them in paper format, but it seems like a waste of resources to have to keep enough bookshelf space for my books!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the algorithm to be *encryption* and not just *hashing*, it must be reversible. To be reversible, the output must contain as much information as the input, and so is unlikely to be significantly shorter.

You may compress the data **before** encryption. There's not a lot else you can do unless you're willing to give up the ability to recover your original text from the ciphertext.

Comment: Compression before encryption won't help in this case, he's using RSA. With a symmetric key system it could help (although that's doubtable at best for such a short message).

Comment: @Darhuuk: Unless his problem is the padding RSA inserts, compressing the plaintext will make the ciphertext smaller. RSA doesn't inherently compress the data, although its output is incompressible.

Comment: The padding is inserted before the encryption step and is there for good reasons (i.e. strengthening the ciphertext against attacks). As such, the padding is an integral part of the RSA algorithm and can't be removed without significantly weakening the resulting ciphertext.

Comment: @Darhuuk: yes, but the length of the padding isn't proportional to the length of the input. Unless the input is very short all the time, the padding won't much matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Change your encryption scheme there are schemes where the size is same as the input size
2. Compress your data before you encrypt, this will be effective only if you have a large block of text to encrypt and then there's the additional overhead of decrypting too.

Comment: i am using rsa- it perform over numbers to convert amit in cipher text first i do a->97 m->109 i->105..and then apply rsa over 97 ,109 ... then i get different integers for 109, 105 or ... i joined that all as a string... this is my process... where i can change my scheme

Comment: "Change your encryption scheme", i.e. change from RSA to something else.

Alternatively you can compress this stream of numbers first and the encrypt the compressed data; this will ensure that the output is also small.

If I'm not wrong, your answer is in HEX, right? ... convert to larger bases to save space. HEX requires 4bits per digit, while a byte has 8bits.

Comment: @rohitamitpathak Just wondering. You're not using these parameters for any serious encryption right? Because with those parameters, you might as well not encrypt. See my post here for a guide on key & parameter sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523089/rsa-the-safety-of-data-protected-by-rsa-in-long-term/5523596#5523596.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to RSA specifically, but: any secure cipher will give output close to indistinguishable from a random bit pattern. A random bit pattern has, per definition, maximum [information theoretic entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory#Quantities_of_information), since for each bit, both 0 and 1 are equally likely.

Now, you want a [lossless compression scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression), since you need to be able to decompress to the exact data you originally compressed. An optimal compression scheme will maximize the entropy of it's output. However, we know that the output of our cipher already has maximum entropy, so we can't possibly increase the entropy.

And thus, trying to compress encrypted data is useless.

*Note*: Depending on your encryption method, compression might be possible, for example, when using a block cipher in [EBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). RSA is a completely different beast altogether though, and, well, compressing won't do anything (except quite possibly make your final output bigger).

*[Edit]* Also, the length of your RSA ciphertext will be in the order of `log n`. With `n` your public modulus. This is the reason that, especially for small plaintexts, public key crypto is extremely 'wasteful'. You normally employ RSA to setup a (smaller, e.g. 128-bit) symmetric key between two parties and then encrypt your data with a symmetric key algorithm such as AES. AES has a block size of 128 bits, so if you do straightforward encryption of your data, the maximum 'overhead' you incur will be `length(message) mod 128` bits.

Answer (score 0):

erm ... you wrote in a comment here that you apply RSA encryption to all single characters:

> i am using rsa- it perform over
>   numbers to convert amit in cipher text
>   first i do a->97 m->109 i->105..and
>   then apply rsa over 97 ,109 ... then i
>   get different integers for 109, 105 or
>   ... i joined that all as a string...

a good advice: **don't do that** since you will lose the security of RSA

if you use RSA in this way, your scheme becomes a substitution-cypher (with only one substitution alphabet) ... given a reasonably long cypher-text or a reasonable number of cypher-texts, this scheme can be broken by analyzing the frequency of cypher-text-chars

see RSAES-OAEP for a padding scheme to apply to your plaintext before encryption